# Code runs multiple times in IE/Opera

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem on my page with code executing multiple times in IE and Opera, though it works in FF, Chrome and Safari. I am using the latest jQuery, the validation plugin and the form plugin. My code originates from the following html:

```
<form action="/case_study/php/survey_submit.php" id="mt_survey" method="post">
...
...             
<fieldset id="submit_button_box">
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit Case Data" />
</fieldset></form>
```

When I click the submit button it should run the following jquery:

```
  $('#mt_survey').submit(function() {
    if ( ($("#mt_survey").valid() == true) || confirm("Unfinished form, continue saving as temporary?")) {
      $('#mt_survey').ajaxSubmit({
         data: {table: "mt_data"},
         target: '#messages',
         success: function() { 
           $('#messages').fadeIn('slow');
           $( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 0  );}
          });
        }
    return false;
   });
```

Now this works when I click the submit button first time. At this point the form is cleared for next set of data. This is done by following code.

```
  $('#clear_form').click(function() {
    $("#mt_survey").resetForm();
    $("#messages").replaceWith('<div id="messages"></div>');
    $("#messages").hide();
    $("#escort_div").hide();
    $("#transport_a_div").hide();
    $("#transport_l_div").hide();
    $("#item_div").hide();
    $("#item2_div").hide();
    $("label.error").hide();
    $("#correction_button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#submit_button").attr('disabled', '');
  });
```

Now once that is done, the form get's filled out again, and submit is clicked again. But this time in IE and Opera the code for it gets run multiple times. I know for sure it's runing multiple times since I checked by putting alerts in there, but mostly it is calling my "survey_submit.php" file multiple times and inserting data into MySQL. Any ideas why? It's been plaguing me for a long time and I see no reason why it's doing so.

Comment: `$("#messages").empty();` instead of `$("#messages").replaceWith('<div id="messages"></div>');`?

Comment: What does resetForm() do? That's not a standard jQuery method that I'm aware of.

Comment: I recommend creating a "counter" in the jquery and set it to 1 if a temp copy of the form is to be saved, otherwise, default 0. On .submit{}, check the counter's value and halt the submission before it gets to the action="" target based on what has been done previously.

Comment: @alexp resetForm() is part of jQuery Validation I think.

Comment: I don't think that there is anything here that would cause that, is there any more code that we could see?

Comment: Is #messages an iFrame or a div?

Comment: There has to be something else going on here. I would cache the selectors and definitely do .empty() instead of replaceWith(), but I don't see anything in this code double-binding or anything weird like that. Do you have the .submit() being defined in a function that gets called twice? the resetForm() should prevent multiple submits. You could even do the reset in the callback function to save yourself a step.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use the form plugin? You could probably get the same effect using

```
$('#mt_survey').submit(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ( ($this.valid() == true) || confirm("Unfinished form, continue saving as temporary?")) {
     $.ajax({
        data: $this.serialize + "&table=mt_data",
        success: function(response) { 
          $('#messages').html(response).fadeIn('slow'); //you may also need to do some processing of the response data before injecting as html
          $( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 0  );}
         });
       }
   return false;
  });
```

And then debugging would be easier

Answer (score 0):

IE and opera are caching the data and using the cache data, that's why you are not able to call next time

Change the code to:

```
$('#mt_survey').ajaxSubmit({
     cache : false,
     data: {table: "mt_data"},
```

I already faced this problem, hope it will help you